# string length and endswith condition not working in Javascript

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

I have a requirement to check the length of the field and its ending letter so that i can update a field based on that.

below is the lightning helper js controller code:

```
 var policyName = helper.getValue(policy, "Name");
    var nullvalue;
           nullvalue = "N/A";     
    if(policyName.length == 12 && policyName.endsWith('0')){
                return nullvalue;
               }
               else{
                  return this.getValue(
                  policyValues,
                  "PolicyValues.TotalAmount"
                );
               }
```

In the UI part, i cannot able to see any value in the field. Based on the above condition, i should see N/A in the field.
Can anyone please suggest the changes in the above code, so that i can get this done.

Thanks!

Comment: you use `getValue()` with `policy` one time and `policyValues` the second, are those supposed to be the same variable?

Comment: @jeremy,No, they are different

Comment: can you confirm what is the policyName coming? Also, you can use default value setting like this - `var nullvalue= "N/A";`

Comment: @ysrshk, the policyname will be like this 012345567780. it is text data type and if the length is 12 and ends with 0, the value in the field should be N/A. Please suggest

Comment: I tried the block - `function test(){
var policyName = '012345567780';
var nullValue = 'N/A';
if(policyName.length == 12 && policyName.endsWith('0') ) 
{ 
return nullValue;
} 
}`

Your code is fine, may be you need to check controller from which helper is getting called and how you're setting it for UI.